# ghost script produce wrong pdf file with diffrent page size

Tags: ghostscript

I am using ghost script version "ghostscript-8.71" to produce pdf file in my application.

In window it produce the pdf file with size "8.26x11.69 (A4)" and Linux 8.5x11 (for India Locale) .

I want to make it consistent as per Window environment. So Linux also produce the same pdf file size i.e "8.26x11.69 (A4)" (for India locale only)

I found the file named "gs_init.ps"
 under the directory "Resource\Init" which contain the settings.
I found while googling ie.

Find the line in "gs_init.ps"

% /DEFAULTPAPERSIZE (a4) def

Then to make A4 the default paper size, uncomment the line to change this to

/DEFAULTPAPERSIZE (a4) def

But it has no effect in Linux. How we can make Linux to produce the pdf file with same size as Window for locale(India).

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks & Regards
Vikas

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, use an up to date version. The current version of Ghostscript is 9.10.

If you read the Ghostscript documentation you will find the same information you googled, in /ghostpdl/gs/doc/Use.htm#Paper_size, section 3.4, where it also says:

"Sometimes the initialization files are compiled into Ghostscript and cannot be changed."

Did you try simply setting -sPAPERSIZE=a4 ?

Comment: Yes I found that "Sometimes the initialization files are compiled into Ghostscript and cannot be changed."....If I am using the latest version ghostcript 9.10, is this going to resolve my problem?

Comment: Did you try the simple solution of setting the papersize ? Try that first. If it does not solve your problem then (probably) you need to add a switch '-I<path>' where <path> points to the initialisation files on disk. GS searches these paths *first* so if you modify init.ps on disk then it will have an effect. Or you can get hold of the latest GS sources and build an executable which doesn't compile the resources into the binary. You should upgrade anyway as you are missing security patches and bug fixes by using such an old version.

Comment: How and where(in which file) I need to set/use the command -sPAPERSIZE=a4 ?